# How to fast .csv files using pandas much faster

Tags: python, pandas, loading

I have a multidimensional dataframe saved in .csv, a quick snippet[image: 3d dataframe]

I am loading this by `df_versus = pd.read_csv("df_versus.csv", index_col=[0, 1, 2])` and it takes up to about 2 minutes, that is very long.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you parsing this CSV data multiple times or only once?

Comment: how CSV  is getting saved, why not other formats if performance is the issue

Comment: You can pass a couple of additional parameters like -  usecols(If you're not using all the columns)  and chunksize.

Comment: @Nk03 Well, I want to save this dataframe to variable in order to use it later in my computations, i guess I am doing that only once. And the point is that i need the whole dataframe so I cant choose specific columns

Comment: @Akhilesh_IN I saved it as pd.to_csv() earlier. I do not know if there are faster formats

Comment: There are other formats - feather is one of the best acc to me.

Comment: instead of saving it in CSV format you can try feather.

Comment: @Nk03 I will try using feather format than, thank a lot

Comment: read https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d

Comment: @Nk03 so I saved it as .feather but I am not able to load this as multiindex frame now, could you help me with that